# PHP let other website know login status of our website

Tags: php, curl, cookies

Let's say I have 2 different computer `computer-x` and `computer-y`. They have different IP address and different session.

I also have 2 website, `abc.com` and `def.abc.com`.

I logged in to `abc.com` by using `computer-x`.

How can I do these:

- If I access `def.abc.com` through `computer-x` which is the same computer I access `abc.com`, I'll get information that I've been already logged in to `abc.com`.
- If I access `def.abc.com` through `computer-y` which is the different computer I access `abc.com`, I'll get information that I'm not logged in to `abc.com`.

I want the user to automatically login to `def.abc.com` if he/she already logged in to `abc.com` without click any button.

I have try to use CURL, but it seems that `abc.com` and `def.abc.com` has different cookies. I cannot access cookie of `abc.com` through `def.abc.com`.

I also try to check if IP address to access `def.abc.com` is equal to IP address that has already logged in to `abc.com`. But this seems not a good solution.

Note: I'm in full control of both `abc.com` and `def.abc.com`.

Comment: Downvoter: Doesn't want to say anything?

Comment: If abc.com and def.abc.com share the same session storage, and you make your cookie valid for all subdomains for abc.com at the time of setting it, it will work exactly as you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we  call single sign on. When we log into google.com, we get logged into all the apps of google i.e. youtube, adsense etc. You can check the available single sign on secure solutions

```
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations
```

You can come up with your own solution as well. May be using intermediate layer..

Comment: Well, I know about single sign on. Just how to implement it correctly?

Comment: probably this one? https://github.com/jasny/sso  ... google out the solutions and use the one which you find easy

Comment: Okay, let's see. Thx. I'll accept your answer later.

Comment: I have see the link, and I'm afraid they just use REMOTE_ADDR and client address to make sure that the request comes from the same computer. Do you think it is secure?

Comment: There are a number of aspects to keep in mind before implementation, I have just the general idea, I have not implemented it before.

Comment: I think, I'll go with this one: http://www.jotlab.com/2008/howto-get-cookies-across-subdomains-php